# Переключение раскладки клавиатуры [левый shift] + [правый shift]

Tags: debian, gnome

Как можно отключить переключение раскладки клавиатуры по нажатию на [левый shift] + [правый shift] ?

Операционная система debian 8 оболочка gnome.

Comment: В настройках пробовали копаться?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/68127/416190